# chrome.downloads.erase for particualr downloaditem ID closes chrome abruptly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Below API call causes chrome to crash. I tried removing query argument but still chrome closes abruptly for erase api call. If we comment this api no issue observed.

```
function eraseDownloadFrmLst(downloadItemID)
{
    chrome.downloads.erase({limit:1, id : downloadItemID},
function(downloadItemID)
    {
        console.log("Erase cancelled download.", downloadItemID);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently when this function was being executed I was getting "unchecked runtime.lasterror Download Already in Progress" for chrome.downloads.pause() API.

Hence to solve it used below code before function entry:

```
chrome.downloads.pause(downloadItem.id,
function()
{
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
    {
        console.log("Paused facing issue" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Paused download before fetching result.");
        // perform our actions
    }
});
```